# How to create a Mongoose Model array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create something like this:

```
var User = mongoose.model('Clicker',
  totalClicks: [
    {type: Number, default: 0},
    {type: Number, default: 0}
  ],
```

I've tried different docs, both about MongoDB and Mongoose. The one that helped me the most was [this one](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) that don't give me a syntax error. But the array is empty, always.

> maxClicks: Array[0] length: 0

How could I build this simple model?

> Appendix

**model.js:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Clicker = mongoose.model('Clicker',
  {
    username: { type: String, unique: true},
    password: { type: String, select: false},
    totalClicks: [
      {type: Number, default: 0},
      {type: Number, default: 0}
    ],
    maxClicks: [
      {type: Number, default: 100},
      {type: Number, default: 100}
    ]
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Clicker', Clicker);
```

Comment: @inspired Done. I've added an expanded version of it.

Comment: please post an example of how you want your mongodb documents to look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a Mongoose Schema object.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Clicker = new Schema({
{
    username: { type: String, unique: true},
    password: { type: String, select: false},
    totalClicks: [{type: Number, default: 0}],
    maxClicks: [{type: Number, default: 100}]
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Clicker', Clicker);
```